# Systematic way to delay rendering until all resources are loaded

Tags: reactjs

I use Webpack 4, Babel 7, React 16.8. My app loads google web fonts, external images required by many components taking part in the initial rendering when users load my pages.

I load fonts with a sass file like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700');
```

I use images within all components like this:

```
import SearchSvg from '../../images/search_icon.svg';
```

and use them like this:

```
<img src={ SearchSvg } />
```

Now I know about `<img onLoad=.....>` and I know there are packages out there to test whether web fonts are already loaded. My question is: Is there any **SYSTEMIC** way/pattern to get the initial rendering of the React components wait until **all** those external resources are loaded?

Right now I use `setTimeout` with `500 ms` to delay the root rendering in my `index.js`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    render(
        ...
    );
}, 500);
```

I would LOVE to replace this hard-coded value with something that actually knows when everything's loaded -- Ideally without having to Add code in every single Component I use.

**The motivation** is of course to avoid Font/Image flickering when I initially render my app -- due to the rendering while images/fonts aren't fully loaded yet.

Comment: tip: `import {ReactComponent as SearchSvg} from '../../images/search_icon.svg'` will use inline SVG in the compiled code (needs proper webpack config, e.g. by using [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs) v2.0 or higher)

Comment: What about using suspense and loading the image with a loader before rendering? 

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense

Comment: Another thought. If your sass file still has to load resources after being loaded, it'll render the component, however the fonts may still be loading.

Comment: Big sites use data url for critical data, that way it is always there. I would however suggest using this only for vector images, normal images should have defined sizes and the rendering once font on load event is fired

Answer (score 3):

You may render your root component after `onload` event is fired.

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets images. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

```
window.onload = function() {
   ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
};
```

If your purpose is to increase performance then I would highly recommend to consider Server Side Rendering.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you could use `document.fonts.ready` to check if the font is ready, and then conditionally render the parts you want once this is true

An example of this is found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts

For your use case, you could use a similar function found at the above link, then set a state value to true if its ready. Then you could conditionally render what you want once this is true

For example:

Call the function in componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.isFontLoaded()
  }
```

The function uses document.fonts.ready, which returns a promise. We then set the state value `fontReady` to true once the promise returns:

```
  isFontLoaded = () => {
    document.fonts.ready.then(this.setState({ fontReady: true }))
  }
```

Only render the the things you want if `fontReady` is true:

```
{fontReady && <img src={ SearchSvg } />}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper component to do all the checks and show a loading or nothing when that's happening and when everything is done, render the application. Something like:

```
class LoadApplication {
  state = { loaded: false }
  timer = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.checkStuff, 50)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }

  checkStuff() {
    if (stuffIsLoaded) {
      this.setState({ loaded: true })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loaded ? this.props.children : null;
  }
}

...

ReactDOM.render(<LoadApplication><App /></LoadApplication>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

This is kinda the same way CRA handles errors. The same way is recommended to catch errors in components in React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) so I think it might be what you're looking for. I hope it helps.